# How to print iterators in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I have been trying to print iterator values in TensorFlow but didn't manage to do that.
here is my code:

```
class Customentropy(keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, name="custom_entropy"):
        super().__init__(name=name)

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        print(y_true)
        print(y_pred)
        a=y_true[0]
        return tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true[0:2] - y_pred))
```

here i have custom loss, so y_true has 3 components and y_pred has 2 components. i want to just compare first two values of each tensorf. when i print those tensors it outputs:

```
Tensor("IteratorGetNext:1", shape=(None, 3), dtype=float32)
Tensor("functional_73/dense_73/Softmax:0", shape=(None, 2), dtype=float32)
```

and huge error. please can you help me to get inforamtion about those two tensors?

what are Tensor("IteratorGetNext:1", shape=(None, 3), dtype=float32)? and how to extract inforamtion from them?

Answer (score 0):

Use [tf.print](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print?version=nightly): `tf.print(y_true)`.

The Tensor objects you see only hold references to the computation graph. When `call` runs, it just builds that computation graph. With `tf.print` the graph will contain the print ops you need so that when it's later executed, it outputs the values you need.

Comment: do you know how to get information from that tensor? out[0:2] or something like that

Comment: Yes, slicing is the best way. e.g. `y_true[0:2]` should work. Also check the `summarize` argument of tf.print, because by default it only prints a few values.

Comment: slicing is not working, anyway thank you for commenting, I solved that problem differently. because of that little problem, I couldn't slice. I made my own training loop. TF is not better than Pytorch. not even close.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Slicing does work for normal Tensors, e.g. `tf.constant([1, 2, 3])[0:2]` returns `[1, 2]`.